# class a:link styling not working

Tags: css

I'm trying to style my links within a div which I've given the class .whatnextnav. The hover styling is working but not the link, it's still inheriting the color: #3CB6CE even thought Firebug says it's not.

Can anyone see a problem with the below?

```
.whatnextnav a:link, a:active, a:visited
  {
  color: #008566;
  text-decoration: none;
  }

.whatnextnav a:hover
  {
  color: #008566;
  text-decoration: underline;
  }
```

Comment: how does your `HTML` look?

Answer (score 2):

When multiple selectors share a single style, the full selector must be used for each selector.  Make the class prefix each selector:

```
.whatnextnav a:link, .whatnextnav a:active, .whatnextnav a:visited
{
  color: #008566;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/9Kqv8/

Comment: Thank you. I knew it was something simple I was missing, just couldn't see the wood for the trees!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it to:

```
.whatnextnav a, .whatnextnav a:active, .whatnextnav a:visited
 {
  color: #008566;
text-decoration: none;
}

.whatnextnav a:hover
 {
color: #008566;
text-decoration: underline;
}
```